# Cocoapod in library for use in App & Extension

Tags: xcode, swift, cocoapods, ios-frameworks, ios-extensions

I am trying to build an iOS app that includes a today extension. As I understand the shared codebase to be used in the app and the extension should be placed in a dynamic framework.

My framework ("AiredKit") uses Alamofire and SwiftyJSON via cocoapods. The framework is then included in the app ("Aired"). I included "AiredKit.framework" in the settings of my target and apparently cocoapods added a "Pods.framework" entry to that same list. Now I can use my framework via a simple `import AiredKit` and code completion and building the app works just fine.

When I try to do the same in my extension "AiredToday" however, Xcode returns an error in at the `import AiredKit` line, stating that the Alamofire and SwiftyJSON modules are missing. Strangely, I couldn't import them even if I wanted to, as they will not be recognized by Xcode.

How can I use my framework properly in my extension ?

Here is my podfile:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'

use_frameworks!

#def aired_kit_pods
    pod "Alamofire",  "~> 1.1"
    pod "SwiftyJSON", "~> 2.1"
#end

target 'AiredKit' do
    link_with 'AiredKit'
end

target 'aired' do
    link_with 'aired'
end

target 'AiredToday' do
    link_with 'AiredToday'
end
```

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Did you find a solution ?